# YouTube thumbnail image not loading in android using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide, android-youtube-api

I am using below code to display Youtube thumbnail:

```
String imageUrl = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + mVideoBeanList.get(position).getThumbnail() + "/default.jpg";
Glide.with(mActivity).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);
```

Sample Path: http://img.youtube.com/vi/wES8gF9V44Q/default.jpg

> Error: java.net.UnknownHostException(Unable to resolve host
>   "img.youtube.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: i got it, its wifi problem, my wifi has limited access and restricting some URL's, when i connect it to mobile data its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your internet connection when you request a youtube thumbnail image.

Comment: Internet connection is available, when i hit sample path in browser its working fine but not in app

Comment: its working now, thanks, its wifi limited access problem